# Rails 7: How can I call pluck on a model referencing an instance method instead of a column name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model named `Category`. It has two columns `plural_name` and `singular_name`. For example, the column values could be 'brother' and 'brethren'.

I have a method named `name` that provides the singular or plural name depending upon the number of particular associations it has.

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entries

  # ...

  def name
    return plural_name if (entries.count > 1 || entries.count.zero?)

    singular_name
  end
end
```

I can do this:

```rb
Category.pluck(:singular_name)
```

But I cannot use pluck with `#name` because it is not a column in the table.

```rb
Category.pluck(:name)

# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "name" does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

Is there any way I can make `#name` appear to Rails as if it is a column in the table? How can I get `Category.pluck(:name)` to work?

Comment: Unfortunately you cant use `pluck` for this. Given your implementation you would probably have to go with go with something like `Category.eager_load(:entries).map(&:name)` which is very inefficient. Another option would be to add a `counter_cache` to the `belongs_to` in the `Entry` model and add a `entries_count` field to `Category`. Then you can leverage that field, which would provide a performance improvement over the former. [See Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) for more info.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind here is that `.count` always creates a count query. Unless thats your intention you want to use `.size` which will use the length if the association is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using `pluck`, we can use `group by` to fetch the names based on a condition like:-

```
Category.select("category.id", "case when array_length(array_agg(entries),1) >1 then categories.plural_name when array_length(array_agg(entries),1) =0 then categories.plural_name else categories.singular_name end as name").
joins(:entries).
group(:category);
```

Comment: Why `array_length(array_agg(entries))` rather than just `COUNT()`? Also if you are taking it out this far you can use `pluck` such that `Category.joins(:entries).group(:id).pluck("SQL FOR name")`. You can limit the logical branching to 2 branches by changing this to something like `IIF(COUNT(entries.id) = 1, singular_name, plural_name)`. Finally `group(:id)` would be limited to PostgreSQL or MySQL with certain features turned off.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
Category.all.map(&:name)
```